# Error when cloning Azure Repos using App Service Editor

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

Currently having a single instance of Web Apps and now trying to control the source code using git. I have used "clone" in Azure Repos and used the following command below to add the remote directory in App Service Editor.

```
git remote add origin [Azure Repos URL]
```

However, the console in App Service Editor shows the following Error message.

```
\ [master]> git remote show origin
fatal: NullReferenceException encountered.
   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

How can I fix this error and use Azure Repos as remote directory from App Service Editor?

Comment: can you check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53150690/fatal-nullreferenceexception-encountered-when-interacting-with-remote)?

Comment: I saw it but I have no idea how to update git on Azure Service Editor.